# How to resize a Konvajs scene with CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, web, konvajs, konva

I am using konvajs to edit the image. I want to make the scene size 500x500 pixels to edit uploaded image but at the same time I need it to be 50%x50% of the parent element to have the same aspect ratio on different screens.
With a simple html canvas, this is easy to do

```
<canvas width="500" height="500" style="width: 50%; height: 50%;"></canvas>
```

But how to do something similar with konvajs?